# cakePHP setFlash cannot find element

Tags: session, cakephp

I am trying to set a success element to my setFlash.

When I do:

```
 $this->Session->setFlash("Message");
```

It shows the message perfectly, however, with a red background. After investigating I can change the element to "success" which should show a nice green background, but when I do:

```
 $this->Session->setFlash("Message","success");
```

I get:

```
 Element Not Found: Elements\success.ctp
```

I have verified and there is definately a success.ctp file within my app/View/Elements/ folder.

I am using cakePHP 2.1

** EDIT **

It may be a routing error as I also find that sometimes on redirect it will redirect example users/users/login as appose to users/login/

Comment: looks fine to me; try clearing your cake cache `APP/tmp/views`

Comment: $this->Session->setFlash('Message.','default',array('class'=>'successMsg'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move the required layout files into app/views/elements (success.ctp)
2. Rename the $content_for_layout variable to $message

[src](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1561/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3).

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion by @Learner, the correct code which worked (for me in 2.1) is:

```
 $this->Session->setFlash('Message.','default',array('class'=>'success'));
```

Answer (score 0):

delete true in  $this->Session->setFlash('Book is Updated!', true);